# MySQL select unused/stale id based on timestamp period

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have an attendance table with simple .user and .timestamp and want to identify any .user **without** a timestamp since a specific time (eg 1 year ago).

I have tried several combinations of between and is not between etc., but can't seem to get the correct output (my logic and SQLs is obviously different :( )

The want to remove 'stale' users (haven't attended for a year).  Once I have the data from the attendance table I will use that to delete records from other tables containing their details.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take a moment to read the guidelines about asking questions on this site. You need to provide complete information and ask specifically targeted questions. Please provide the code you've tried and explain HOW it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

To Delete:

```
DELETE FROM userattendance WHERE user_id IN (SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE mytimestamp < (UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - 31557600))
```

It's pretty much saying DELETE data from the user attendance table where mytimestamp field is less than the current unix timestamp minus a year for any user.

Comment: I think DELETE is supposed to be deleting from other table :) don't let op to delete original data accidentally.

Comment: Thanks, that got it - even though on my first post I missed adding the code etc, you got it done.  Cheers.